# How to just load the latest version of dll from GAC

Tags: c#, binding, gac

I've written a batch execution framework and in it I want (in some scenarios) to load an assembly from the GAC where there may be multiple versions but I just want to load the *latest version*.
Is this even possible?

TIA

Answer (score 3):

`Assembly.LoadWithPartialName(string)` will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use  a publisher policy with a BindingRedirect. See this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185187/how-to-make-publisher-policy-file-redirect-assembly-request).

Answer (score -2):

[Linq to Gac](http://blog.domaindotnet.com/2008/09/20/fusion_c_sharp_wrapper_for_linq_to_gac_access/) can query the GAC. You can [load assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.load.aspx) at runtime once you know what you want.