# Error adding policy file to GAC

Tags: gac, policy, publisher

I'm trying to add a publisher policy file to the gac as per this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283419/how-to-just-load-the-latest-version-of-dll-from-gac) but I'm having problems when I try and add the file on my test server.

I get "A module specified in the manifest of assembly 'policy.3.0.assemblyname.dll' could not be found"

My policy file looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="*assemblyname*"
                          publicKeyToken="7a19eec6f55e2f84"
                          culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.0.0.0"
                         newVersion="3.0.0.1"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Please help!

Thanks

Ben

---

I've recreated the problem from scratch with a new assembly that has no dependancies (apart from the defaults) itself - all works fine on my local development machine (and redirects fine too) but gives the same error adding the policy file to the GAC on the server!

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="TestAsm"
                          publicKeyToken="5f55456fdcc9b528"
                          culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.0.0.0"
                         newVersion="3.0.0.1"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

linked in the following way

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\al.exe /link:PublisherPolicy.xml /out:policy.3.0.TestAsm.dll /keyfile:..\..\key.snk /version:3.0.0.0
pause
```

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow - ok got it.

I should have paid more attention to exactly what this meant

[(MSDN) How to: Create a Publisher Policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz32563a.aspx)

> Important Note:  The publisher policy
>   assembly cannot be added to the global
>   assembly cache unless the original
>   publisher policy file is located in
>   the same directory as the assembly .

That requirement is, frankly, so bizarre that it didn't register.  The original policy file, that was compiled into the assembly i'm trying to add to the gac, has to be in the same folder as the policy assembly as you add the policy assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Ok...just want to check some basics....

You definitely have got both versions of the dependent assembly installed to GAC?

And have you verified that the version numbers in the [assembly: AssemblyVersion()] attribute are correct.

And you did use [assembly: **AssemblyVersion**()] and *NOT* [assembly: **AssemblyFileVersion**("1.0.0.1")].

**Update:** My mistake, you only need the latest version of the assembly in the GAC. I just tried that here and it works. My only other thoughts are to check that the public key tokens are the same and that you've not misspelled the assembly name.

Also when you generate the policy file make sure you use the /version switch in the assembly linker to explicitly set the version number to 3.0.0.0 *AND* don't specify the /platform switch. e.g.

```
al.exe /link:assembly.config /out:policy.3.0.assembly.dll 
         /keyfile:mykey.snk /version:3.0.0.0
```

Comment: thanks for replying
No I've only got the target version of the assembly in the GAC (3.0.0.1) - but this works on my dev machine (well it installs to the GAC, not sure if it redirects ok yet). Do I have to have the non-used version in the GAC if I want to do this redirect? Assembly version and Assembly File version are both set to 3.0.0.1

Comment: Actually it seems you only need the latest version of the assembly in the GAC, so apologies for that red herring.

Comment: I added some more comments to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To add policy assemblies to the GAC using Wise, you do the same thing as you do to add the assembly the policy is for.  So you add the policy assembly to the "Global Assembly Cache" in Wise, and as long as you have the policy file (.config) in the same location on the machine, Wise will automatically add it to GAC as well.