# How would I load an assembly from the GAC?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I'm trying to use Assembly.Load() to load an assembly that is in the GAC. For example, say I want to list out all of the types that exist in **PresentationCore.dll**, how would I go about loading **PresentationCore.dll**?

When I try this:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.Load("PresentationCore.dll");
```

I get a **FileNotFoundException**. [Another answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283419/how-to-just-load-the-latest-version-of-dll-from-gac/283880#283880) suggested I used Assembly.LoadFrom() to accomplish this - I'm hesitant to do that because Assembly.LoadFrom() is deprecated, according to Visual Studio 2008 - plus, it doesn't seem to actually work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the assembly is in the GAC you must load it via its fully qualified name.

For example, if I wanted to load `mscorlib.dll` I would do something like this:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.Load
    ("mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
```

The easiest way to determine an assembly's fully qualified name is to load the assembly in [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and use the **Name** field from the lower display pane like this:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You need to pass the name of the assembly to `Assembly.Load()`, not the name of the DLL. If you open the DLL in Reflector, the name should be at the bottom of the window. In the case of PresentationCore.dll, the name should be something like `PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35`.

Comment: +1 good point - it's the logical name of the assembly - not the physical file name - that's needed

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you take a look at [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(VS.71).aspx) in the MSDN library to get an idea of what happens when the CLR attempts to load an assembly.

For diagnosing specific issues, the [Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(vs.71).aspx) tool is fantastic. Suzanne Cook, one of the Fusion developers has a [guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx) on her blog which has helped me out in the past.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get the string is to first add a reference to your project then do this:

```
string regStringMath = typeof(System.Math).Assembly;
Assembly assMath = Assembly.Load("System.Math", regStringMath);

string regStringPres = typeof(PresentationCore).Assembly;
Assembly assPres = Assembly.Load("PresentationCore", regStringPres);
```

This will ensure you get the right version that you added as a reference to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Use GetAssemblyName (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.getassemblyname.aspx) to get the fully qualified assembly name of the dll, and pass this to Assembly.Load().