# C#, Shared Assemblies, publisher policy not working, MS VS .NET 2013

Tags: c#

I can't figured out how to use a publisher policy correctly and I seem to have an similiar issue as related to:

[How to make Publisher Policy file redirect assembly request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185187/how-to-make-publisher-policy-file-redirect-assembly-request)

I've created shared assemply named "SharedAssembly.dll" in version "1.0.0.0", and then in version "2.0.0.0". Both are instaled in GAC (MSIL_GAC, target is .NET Framework 4.5).

I've created following publisher policy file *.xml (redirecting to an older version "1.0.0.0" is on purpose behaviour):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity
          name="SharedAssembly"
          publicKeyToken="89f6ea550599ca14"
          culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0"
                       newVersion="1.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Then I've created the publisher policy assembly using the command:

```
al /link:App.config /out:policy.2.0.SharedAssembly.dll /keyf:F:\VisualStudio\klucz.snk /v:1.0.0.0 /platform:anycpu
```

Of course, I installed it into GAC.

Then I created a new Console Application, I added reference to the "SharedAssembly.dll", but it doesn't work :(

It still connects with the 2.0.0.0 version of my shared assembly.

I tried many advices, as using fuslogvw.exe (no errors shown), getting rid of the "culture" attribute, etc., but it doesn't help.

I think the problem is not that I want to point to the older version of .dll?

Please help me to fix that issue, cause I've tried so many things and yet I can't make it work.

Comment: Show the Fuslogvw trace you got.  Log all binds.

Comment: Ok.. I just pressed "F5" once more and it works. I don't know how in the world this is possible 'cause I've done this thousands of times. Anyway, I think this must have been a #bug? :)